# Python Executable failed to execute the script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am facing an error when making an executable with pyinstaller.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\app\\label_printing\\dist\\label_printing\\treepoem\\postscriptbarcode\\barcode.ps'
[6176] Failed to execute script label_printing
```

Comment: What part of the error are you not understanding? The file is not found. We can't help with that, that's a local issue. The only thing is to suggest reading [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python) to make sure you are using the path correctly

Answer (score 1):

Pyinstaller is used to convert **.py** files to **.exe**.

You are trying to convert **barcode.ps**, which is a photoshop file.

Moreover, the error is because this file is not in this location:

```
C:\app\label_printing\dist\label_printing\treepoem\postscriptbarcode
```

Comment: Thanks I have copied the file to that location , then its working fine ...

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to the .exe as well with "--add-data" command when executing pyinstaller

```
pyinstaller --onefile label_printing.py --console --add-data "C:\\barcode.ps;treepoem\\postscriptbarcode"
```